# how to check two json and yaml files to compare

Tags: python

This is the `yaml` file (the `type` field is both in Persian and English, and also `Type TypeB` is correct and is not a typo):

```
-
    dedicatedip: 1.1.1.1
    status: Active
    type: 'نوع اول'
-
    dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
    status: Active
    type: 'Type TypeB'
-
    dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
    status: Active
    type: 'نوع اول'
-
    dedicatedip: 3.3.3.3
    status: Suspended
    type: 'Type TypeC'
-
    dedicatedip: 3.3.3.3
    status: Active
    type: 'نوع اول'
-
```

This is the `json` file:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "data": {
    "licenses": [
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "cycle": "monthly",
        "type": "typeA",
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "renewDate": "2023-12-22 09:10:00",
        "status": "Active",
        "hostname": "some.fqdn.co.com",
        "autoRenew": true
      },
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "cycle": "monthly",
        "type": "typeB",
        "ip": "2.2.2.2",
        "renewDate": "2023-12-22 09:10:00",
        "status": "Suspended",
        "hostname": "some.fqdn.co.com",
        "autoRenew": true
      },
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "cycle": "monthly",
        "type": "typeA",
        "ip": "2.2.2.2",
        "renewDate": "2023-12-22 09:10:00",
        "status": "Active",
        "hostname": "some.fqdn.co.com",
        "autoRenew": true
      },
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "cycle": "monthly",
        "type": "typeC",
        "ip": "3.3.3.3",
        "renewDate": "2023-12-22 09:10:00",
        "status": "Active",
        "hostname": "some.fqdn.co.com",
        "autoRenew": true
      },
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "cycle": "monthly",
        "type": "typeA",
        "ip": "3.3.3.3",
        "renewDate": "2023-12-22 09:10:00",
        "status": "Active",
        "hostname": "some.fqdn.co.com",
        "autoRenew": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm going to to this over iterating both files:

```
check if the ip of json and yaml match, if it matches then check the type of both (case-insensitive), then if they both match, now if status don't match then print something.

Since one IP may have several license types, the `type` should be matched too.
```

The expected output:

```
ip 2.2.2.2, license typeB "active" in "yaml" but "suspended" in "json".
ip 3.3.3.3, license typeA "suspended" in "yaml" but "active" in json.
```

I tried to write a code, but this is my attempt so far:

```
import json
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

file_name = 'file.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

json_names = []
for r in data:
    for j in r['data']:
        if j is not None and 'licenses' in j and j['licenses'] is not None and 'ip' in j['licenses']:
            json_names.append({'licenses': j['licenses']['ip'] })


yaml = YAML()
with open('file.yaml') as file:
    code = yaml.load(file)

yaml_names = []
for d in code:
    yaml_names.append({'ip': d['dedicatedip']})
```

But I'm not sure what to do next for what I'm trying to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
import json, yaml

with (
    open("file.yaml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as yf,
    open("file.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as jf
):
    ydata = list(yaml.safe_load_all(yf)); jdata = json.load(jf)
    
    delta = [
        (yd["dedicatedip"], jd["type"], yd["status"], jd["status"])
        for yd in ydata[0] for jd in jdata["data"]["licenses"]
        if yd and yd["dedicatedip"] == jd["ip"]
        and yd["type"].removeprefix("Type ").lower() == jd["type"].lower()
        and yd["status"] != jd["status"]
    ]
```

Output(s) :

```
print(delta)
# [('2.2.2.2', 'typeB', 'Active', 'Suspended'),
#  ('3.3.3.3', 'typeC', 'Suspended', 'Active')]

for vals in delta:
    print('IP {}, license {} "{}" in YAML but "{}" in JSON.'.format(*vals))

# IP 2.2.2.2, license typeB "Active" in YAML but "Suspended" in JSON.
# IP 3.3.3.3, license typeC "Suspended" in YAML but "Active" in JSON.

for vals in delta:
    print(*map("{:<10}".format, vals))
# 2.2.2.2    typeB      Active     Suspended 
# 3.3.3.3    typeC      Suspended  Active
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `SyntaxError` in line 4 `as yf`.

Comment: Works fine here, I can't reproduce (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs7sZ.png)). Can you make a *screenshot* ?

Comment: What's your Python version? I use 3.8.10 in Ubuntu. I edited the question.

Comment: I use 3.11. You can try using two `with` statements (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL2X7.png)) instead of one.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'`

Comment: I'm using `removeprefix` in my code and not `noremoveprefix`. Check yours please!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it manually on the comments and it was a typo. `removeprefix` was the error.

Comment: [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) was added in 3.9. So you can replace `yd["type"].removeprefix("Type ").lower()` with `yd["type"].replace("Type ", "").lower()`

Comment: Thanks, this is fixed. But how do you check the word `نوع اول` with `TypeA`?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. Your question becomes now a moving target and I'm not sure people here can speak Persian. Is making a mapping of the types would solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks, got it. Just a hint: is it proper to add variable for these?

Comment: Yes but I feel like whatever solution I'd propose, you'll always find something to ask for more, `∞`.

Comment: No:) I won't do that:( Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll add variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255980/discussion-between-timeless-and-saeed).